# How can I use the Android back button to move back within my app instead of closing my app?

Tags: java, android, callback

My app has three activities, A, B and C. I am moving from A to B through an OK button, and I want to move back from B to A by using the default back button of Android devices. When I press the button, though, the entire app gets closed. How can I get around this problem?

Comment: Show your code which is runned then button is clicked. How are you starting B from A?

Comment: if the answers don't help you stop silently downvoting it. Comment please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect you call `finish()` in your OK button onclick listener. Don't do that. `finish()` removes your activity from activity stack.

Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Answer (score 2):

why start your activity for result ? when you press the backbutton, the result is set to RESULT_CANCELED form the B activity, so it crashes if you don't handle the resultcode...

you can handle the backpress like this

```
private static final int NONE = -1;

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

   setResult(NONE, intent);
        finish();
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: It is incorrect to say that no result is returned when the back button is pressed. The result returned will be RESULT_CANCELED, which is equal to 0

Comment: oh i didn't know this, i thought it was just that my app didn't handle the case 0 . thanks for the precision !

Answer (score 1):

When you are Ok button r u starting an intent...like

**Intent int=new intent(context,B.class);
startActivity(int);**

then if you are not handling backbutton.

If use default back button...**it will goes back to A.**

Hope it helps...

Comment: i am using the following line to move from my main class         Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Add.class); startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

Answer (score 0):

In my onClick method (in Main Activity) I use the code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
 context.startActivityForResult(intent, SecondActivity.SECONDACTIVITY_REQUEST);
```

In the manifest I've got:

```
 <activity android:name=".SecondActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:launchMode="standard"></activity>
```

This works for me without any other settings that I can see.  What events are you responding to?

Note that you can also go back an activity, in code like this:

```
super.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
super.finish();
```

Edit...
Make sure you're not swallowing the event in the Main Activitys onKeyDown event.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    //your code here
    //if (keyCode ==
    //...
    //else
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```