# Android device Back Button close the app not move to Main Activity

Tags: android

How can I use the Android back button to move back within my app instead of closing my app?
this is my activity stack
Activity A (Main Activity)  OK button press -->Activity B OK button Press  -->Activity C

When i tab the device Back button  it moves to Activity B then again i press the back button app get close (move to android home screen)

I need to go to Main Activity when user back press on Activity B?

NOTE: Im not calling any finish() when moving to next activity..

Sam

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use the Android back button to move back within my app instead of closing my app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406919/how-can-i-use-the-android-back-button-to-move-back-within-my-app-instead-of-closi)

Comment: I really think you do need to post your code where you are starting Activity B from Activity A. Also post your AndroidManifest.xml (at least the section showing the <activity> details for all of your activities.

Comment: I'm glad this was posted. While debugging I added a similar line and had the same problem. Finding this made it way easy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you really really sure that you are not calling finish? Try a search on finish for the entire app.

Comment: ya Mike i have delete that line also.. no more finish() find even i search the entire app, 100% sure no finish() method.

Comment: as you said that you comment it now... so basically it was there... try to clean and build your app, sometimes it doesn't update the apk... just a guess.. :)

Comment: your correct i deleted the target folder and did clean build it's worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [How can I use the Android back button to move back within my app instead of closing my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406919/how-can-i-use-the-android-back-button-to-move-back-within-my-app-instead-of-closi)

Actually, it should not happen unless you are calling finish() because android works with activity stack and as you keep pressing device back button, it calls previous activity on stack.

Comment: well i read that post as well, still i can't figure it out why it's not open the Main Activity. i haven't override the back button method even, any activity filter might cause this problem...

Comment: Try deploying your application again or post your code possibly.

Answer (score 0):

Check your AndroidManifest.xml and see if your activity node contains this line:

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

If the parent activity has the line above, any new activity opened won't be kept in the activity stack.